# WPF Combobox binding

Tags: wpf, binding, combobox

I got two Comboboxes and both of them have binding with the same Source.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource UsersViewSource}}"
```

And when I change something in the first one, it reflects also to the second one. And I dunno how to keep their SelectedItem values separately, using the same ItemsSource.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms593279(v=VS.90).aspx) property should be set to False:

> true if the SelectedItem is always
>   synchronized with the current item in
>   the ItemCollection; false if the
>   SelectedItem is never synchronized
>   with the current item; null if the
>   SelectedItem is synchronized with the
>   current item only if the Selector uses
>   a CollectionView. The default value is
>   null.

**Here's a sample:**

```
<Page
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Page.Resources>
      <x:Array x:Key="myStrings" Type="sys:String">
         <sys:String>one</sys:String>
         <sys:String>two</sys:String>
         <sys:String>three</sys:String>
         <sys:String>four</sys:String>
         <sys:String>five</sys:String>
      </x:Array>
   </Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Width="200">
    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False" Margin="25"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myStrings}}" />

    <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"  Margin="25"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myStrings}}" />
</StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Comment: The irony of your answer is that - as your quote explains - the `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"` in your quoted code is completely unnecessary, because you're not binding to a `CollectionView`.  If you take those attributes out, the comboboxes still aren't linked.

Comment: Agreed that it may not be the best example, but set the value to True and they do synchronize as if they were bound to a CollectionView (my assumption). If indeed this does not work with a CollectionView, then be all means I shall delete the answer and walk away learning something myself.

Comment: Threw together a quick project and tested to see if the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property will work with a CollectionView and it does indeed work. Admittedly my answer isn't exactly correct, but it does provide a quick Kaxaml example ;)

Answer (score 2):

You just need to set the [`IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx) property to false (by default it's null)

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess (from the name of your binding) that the reason this is happening is that you're binding to a `CollectionViewSource` (that wraps a collection).  This class is a proxy that WPF uses that includes (amongst other things) the selected item of a collection.  Obviously if you're sharing this collection between two comboboxes, you're also sharing the selected item.

If you set `ItemsSource` to something that's *not* a `CollectionViewSource`, the control will automatically wrap it in one.  So, my suggestion would be to bind directly to a collection instead of wrapping in a `CollectionViewSource` - or, alternatively, create two `CollectionViewSource` instances, one for each `ComboBox`.

Answer (score 0):

You can separately bind the SelectedItem property for each combo box separately.

i.e.

```
SelectedItem={Binding SelectedItem1}
```

This way when each one's item gets set, it gets stored into a different place.