# Wpf ListBoxes' ItemsSource strange behaviour

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

**Edited** to address [F Ruffell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713688/wpf-listboxes-itemssource-strange-behaviour/7713939#7713939)

I have the following xaml

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="_list1"/>
    <ListBox x:Name="_list2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and this code-behind:

```
var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
_list1.ItemsSource = ints;
_list2.ItemsSource = ints;

_list1.Items.Filter = i => ((int)i) < 2;
```

For some reason after setting filter only for the first `ListBox` **both lists are filtered**. I expect the lists to have completely different `CollectionViews` and indeed `_list1.Items != _list2.Items`. Meanwhile setting filter to one of them also somehow sets that very filter to the other.
The question is **why** and **how** are `CollectionViews` synchronized?

Comment: You will find this article helpful http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/11/05/itemscontrol-c-is-for-collection/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The question is why and how are CollectionViews synchronized?

They are synchronized because even though both `ListBoxes` have different `Items`, they share the same `CollectionView`, which is the default view for the source collection.

The `Items` property of `ItemsControl` is of type `ItemCollection` and the `CollectionView` property of `ItemCollection` is *internal* so we can't access it directly to verify that this is true. However, we can just enter these three values in the debugger to verify this, they all come out as true

```
_list1.Items.CollectionView == _list2.Items.CollectionView // true
_list1.Items.CollectionView == CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ints) // true
_list2.Items.CollectionView == CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ints) // true
```

Alternatively, we can use reflection to do the comparison in code

```
PropertyInfo collectionViewProperty =
    typeof(ItemCollection).GetProperty("CollectionView", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
ListCollectionView list1CollectionView = collectionViewProperty.GetValue(_list1.Items, null) as ListCollectionView;
ListCollectionView list2CollectionView = collectionViewProperty.GetValue(_list2.Items, null) as ListCollectionView;
ListCollectionView defaultCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ints) as ListCollectionView;

Debug.WriteLine(list1CollectionView == list2CollectionView);
Debug.WriteLine(list1CollectionView == defaultCollectionView);
Debug.WriteLine(list2CollectionView == defaultCollectionView);
```

The way to work around this has already been posted by *F Ruffell*, create a new `ListCollectionView` as `ItemsSource` for each `ListBox`.

```
_list1.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(ints);
_list2.ItemsSource = new ListCollectionView(ints);
```

*Also note that after this, the 3 comparisons above comes out as false*

Comment: Thanks for your investigation. Microsoft article on [CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx) confirmed your point. Although I still cannot imagine why WPF reuses CollectionView instead of creating a new one for each list.

Comment: The collectionview is reused so that each itemsource binding will have a default view without throwing lots of new, largely redundant (and often underused) collectionviews into memory. This behaviour is over-ridable expressly for this reason. It has to be one or the other, and keeping object counts lean is the most efficient default.

Answer (score 7):

When you set the `ItemsSource` WPF actually creates a `CollectionView` from the specified `IEnumerable`. It does this so that there is a notion of a selected item(s), filtering, grouping etc (none of which are supported by the `IEnumerable` assigned to the `ItemsSource`). When the same underlying collection is used more than once, WPF will synchronized the two CollectionViews.
If you don't want this behaviour, simply set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `False` on each `ListBox`.

For more information see:

[WPF Combobox binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458420/wpf-combobox-binding)

**Edit**

Upon further investigation it appears as though setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` really only applies to the selected item, and all other properties across the two `ICollectionViews` are still synchronized (even though each `ListBox` has its own `ICollectionView` - changing the `Filter` or adding a `SortDescription` to one, will add it to the other, you learn something new everyday :) ).

To change this behaviour, you need to create the `ICollectionView` for each `ListBox` yourself and then directly modify the `Filter` property, for example:

```
        var ints = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var viewOne = new ListCollectionView(ints);
        var viewTwo = new ListCollectionView(ints);
        _list1.ItemsSource = viewOne;
        _list2.ItemsSource = viewTwo;

        viewOne.Filter = i => ((int)i) < 2;
```

Cheers!

Comment: You can also achieve the same effect by setting `ItemsSource` to a new instance of an appropriate `ICollectionView` (e.g. `new ListCollectionView(ints)`)

Comment: My first thought was that WPF reuses `CollectionView`. There are two problem here: 1) I cannot understand, why? 2) _list1.Items != _list2.Items. And also, setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `false` did not help.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: An ItemsSource control does not interact with a collection directly. It uses a `CollectionView`. When you set the `ItemsSource` to a collection, it will automatically call `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(...)` to get a `CollectionView` for that collection, and use that instead. Calling `GetDefaultView(...)` for the same collection gives you the same instance of `CollectionView`, and so both `ListBox`es are using the same `CollectionView` which causes this syncronization. Like this answer outlines, you must explicitly create a new `CollectionView` to avoid this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the reference type and giving both the Listboxes same itemSource if you manipulate one other one will also be manipulated. If you want to achive this just use new and reassign the second listbox  before you give it to ItemsSource.