# WPF DataGridTemplateColumn Binding Behavior

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid

I have a DataGridTemplateColumn setup below.  My issue is when I change a row employee using the combobox, I see some other rows change values as well.  I figured it was related to the binding somehow, but it is weird because I can't seem to see my itemsource datacontext (Tasks) while inside the celleditingtemplate but i can inside the celltemplate.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="EmployeeViewSource" Source="{Binding Path=Employees}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
     <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tasks}">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Employee Name">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource EmployeeViewSource}}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=EmployeeID}" SelectedValuePath="EmployeeID" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Employee.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The relevant ViewModel like similiar to below:

```
Class TaskViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Task> Tasks { get; private set; }
    Public ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees { get; private set; }

}
```

The Tasks/Employee Models are both entity generated classes that have some fields.

---

Update: I am starting to think maybe this has to do with the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem property.  Perhaps all of the comboboxes are trying to sync because there binding collection current selected is channging.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give us a simplified version of your view models ? Besides, you have no binding defined on your column, which may be a source of error.

Comment: The binding for the column resides in the templates. The textbox is displaying the information fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following a lead on the 'IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem' property, it seems the answer lies with the ComboBox. Here is a more detailed explanation:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458420/wpf-combobox-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458420/wpf-combobox-binding/)

Comment: I don't think is the same case. Weird though, your code seems correct.